# Moq .net controller method object

Tags: .net, tdd, moq

I'm learning TDD together with .net MVC. Now ive got so far that i want to moq my method input object which isn't possible by the way i try it.

To be able to Moq I've created a Interface of the class and used it as input object in my controller method. This works fine and i can actually Moq it. 
Problem is when i try to run the program as intended, it wont work as the framework is trying to create the object on post and interfaces cant be initialized that way.

How do i bypass this? I really dont want to create a class object in my test and send it in.

Code looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Setup(ISetup gameSetup)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
       return RedirectToAction("Start", gameSetup);

   return View("SetupView");
}
```

So I want to Moq the Setup class or Interface in this exampel.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom `ModelBinder` in order to bind your HTTP response data to some instance of `ISetup`. Inside model binder you will need to instantiate a concrete implementation of `ISetup` and fill it with appropriate data from HTTP response.